# Suppressing Warnings when using a dynamic class reference

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, hashmap, instantiation

## Background

An existing system creates a plethora of `HashMap` instances via its `Generics` class:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Generics {
  public static <K,V> Map<K, V> newMap() {
    return new HashMap<K,V>();
  }

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    Map<String, String> map = newMap();
  }
}
```

This is the single point of creation for all instances of classes that implement the `Map` interface. We would like the ability to change the map implementation without recompiling the application. This would allow us to use Trove's `THashMap`, for example, to optimize the application.

## Problem

The software cannot be bundled with Trove's `THashMap` due to licensing conditions. As such, it would be great if there was a way to specify the name of the map to instantiate at runtime (for those people who have no such licensing restrictions). For example:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import gnu.trove.map.hash.THashMap;

public class Generics {
  private String mapClassName = "java.util.HashMap";

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <K,V> Map<K,V> newMap() {
    Map<K,V> map;

    try {
      Class<? extends Map<K,V>> c = (Class<Map<K,V>>)Class.forName(
        getMapClassName() ).asSubclass( Map.class );
      map = c.newInstance();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
      map = new HashMap<K,V>();
    }

    return map;
  }

  protected String getMapClassName() {
    return this.mapClassName;
  }

  protected void setMapClassName( String s ) {
    this.mapClassName = s;
  }

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    Generics g = new Generics();
    Map<String, String> map = g.newMap();
    System.out.printf( "Class = %s\n", map.getClass().toString() );

    g.setMapClassName( "gnu.trove.map.hash.THashMap" );
    map = g.newMap();
    System.out.printf( "Class = %s\n", map.getClass().toString() );
  }
}
```

## Question

Is there a way to avoid the `@SupressWarnings` annotation when compiling with `-Xlint` and still avoid the warnings?

Comment: You probably want to precalculate `c` and store the result in a static  (and recalculate when `setMapClassName` is called) -- `Class.forName` is a little expensive to rerun every time you want a map.

Comment: I suspect the answer to the question you asked is "no" but I'd loved to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation when compiling with `-Xlint` and still avoid the warnings?

No. `Class.forName` returns a `Class<?>`. The only way to assign it to `Class<? extends Map<K, V>>` is to do an unchecked cast. Sometimes unchecked casts are necessary, and so using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is acceptable here (provided you document the reason well).

IMHO it would be more correct to keep a reference to `Class<? extends Map<?, ?>>` and then do an unchecked cast of the result of `newInstance` to `Map<K,V>`. I only say this because a `Class` object is a canonical representation of a raw type, so a type like `Class<? extends Map<K, V>>` is slightly misleading.

---

This is outside the scope of the question, but here's a suggested alternative for your solution:

```
public interface MapFactory {
    <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap() throws Exception;
}

public enum HashMapFactory implements MapFactory {

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap() {
        return new HashMap<K, V>();
    }
}

public static final class DynamicMapFactory implements MapFactory {

    private final Constructor<? extends Map<?, ?>> constructor;

    private DynamicMapFactory(Constructor<? extends Map<?, ?>> constructor) {
        this.constructor = constructor;
    }

    @Override
    //Impl note: these checked exceptions could also be wrapped in RuntimeException
    public <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //this is okay because the default ctor will return an empty map
        final Map<K, V> withNarrowedTypes = (Map<K, V>)constructor.newInstance();
        return withNarrowedTypes;
    }

    public static DynamicMapFactory make(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //Class<? extends Map> can safely be cast to Class<? extends Map<?, ?>>
        final Class<? extends Map<?, ?>> type =
                (Class<? extends Map<?, ?>>)Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Map.class);
        final Constructor<? extends Map<?, ?>> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor();

        return new DynamicMapFactory(constructor);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Integer> map1 = HashMapFactory.INSTANCE.newMap();
    Map<String, Integer> map2 = DynamicMapFactory.make("java.util.TreeMap").newMap();

    System.out.println(map1.getClass()); //class java.util.HashMap
    System.out.println(map2.getClass()); //class java.util.TreeMap
}
```